# Unable to create user PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to create new user after I login with facebook/google, but getting error with:

> error_handler.js:46 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission deniedErrorHandler.handleError @
>   error_handler.js:46next @ application_ref.js:291schedulerFn @
>   async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @
>   PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

my rules are:

```
 "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with Facebook
        ".read": "auth !== null && (auth.provider === 'facebook' || auth.provider === 'google')" 
      }
    }
```

when I remove my rules all works ok.

My code is:

```
  private createNewUser(user: any): any {
    const newUser = this.af.database.object('users/' + user.uid);
    newUser.set({
      username: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      profile_picture: user.avatar,
      provider : user.provider,
      create_date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "")})

  }
```

what fileds do i need to check?

Comment: If you `console.log(user)` in `createNewUser()` does it show an object with a `uid` property?

Comment: yes I have this uid on user, @FrankvanPuffelen is this ok to use   ".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid", when I want to creat a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use this rules for users.

```
 "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "!data.exists() || auth.uid === $uid",
        // grants read access to any user who is logged in with Facebook
        ".read": "auth !== null && (auth.provider === 'facebook' || auth.provider === 'google')" 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in your rules. 
You allow write access only for existing users who already has `uid` under `users/uid` node but it you do not allow write access on `users` node.

You need to allow write access under `users` node. But this will cascade, which means that none of the `.write` rules under `users` node will be checked if `.write` rule under users node will evaluate to true. So you need to change your existing `.write` to `.validate`.

```
"users": {
  // Grant every logged in user to write here
  ".write": "auth !== null",
  "$uid": {
    // .validate rule will restrict .write if current user id does not match the key ($uid)
    ".validate": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
    // grants read access to any user who is logged in with Facebook
    ".read": "auth !== null && (auth.provider === 'facebook' || auth.provider === 'google')" 
  }
}
```

For more information about how to setup your security rules, read the following link and watch the video on this link.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: but anther user can read some one details ? because of the read...am I right?